# sql71501 sql parameter has unresolved reference to build-in type Visual Studio 2012 DB project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, project, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting the following error with my database project in VS2012. The problem started when I added a custom type in my Database project in VS2012.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DestAttractions] AS TABLE(
[TAAttractionId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[TARatingImgUrl] [varchar](256) NULL,
[TAReviewCount] [int] NULL,
[TAReviewUrl] [varchar](256) NULL)
```

When I try to reference the type in stored procedure which is also part of the database project

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spupd_DestinationTripAdvisorData]
@DestinationId INT,
@TAAwardImgUrl VARCHAR(256),
@Attractions dbo.DestAttractions READONLY
AS
BEGIN

------
------
END
```

And build the database project I keep on getting the following error which is quite annoying since the stored procedure works flawlessly and there is no problem with the type.

> SQL71501: Parameter:
>   [dbo].[spupd_DestinationTripAdvisorData].[@Attractions] has an
>   unresolved reference to Built-in Type [dbo].[DestAttractions]. Any
>   pointers or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try rebuilding the project, or try again after closing VS and reopening it. I've seen this behavior before with custom types and never quite understood why it happens.

Comment: Also check the custom type's file properties in VS and make sure Build Action is set to Build.

Comment: Thanks Keith. That worked like a charm. Can't believe I missed the build action for the type's file properties.

Answer (score 12):

In my case the solution was to change the **Build Action** of file what contains the type definition to **Build**.